# Return QString value from void method inside a class

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

file.cpp

```
fileTxt::fileTxt()
{

}

fileTxt::~fileTxt()
{

}

void fileTxt::setFileTxt(Ui::Dialog *ui)
{
    QString fileName="test.txt"
}

void fileTxt::elabFileTxt(Ui::Dialog *ui)
{
    ui->label_7->setText(fileName);
}
```

i have two methods inside the class fileTxt. 
In the method setFileTxt, i set the QString member fileName, to test.txt. 
In the file.h fileName is set to private. 
Why fileName is not passed into elabFileTxt method if the two methods are in the same class? The label_7 prints nothing. If i use "file name" the label_7 prints file name.

Comment: This is a very basic question. I suggest you take some time to look over the fundamentals of C++ prior to implementing code in Qt. "The C++ Programming Language"(B.Stroustrup) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redeclaring and defining a local variable instead of your class global variable, what you want is this:

```
void fileTxt::setFileTxt(Ui::Dialog *ui)
{
    fileName="test.txt";
}
```

Comment: Yes, its a very new bie (me) mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return a `QString` from a function with a `void` return type.

But you can use an advantage of Object Orientation here.

You add a `QString` member to the class and set it.

```
class fileTxt //...
{
    //...
    private:
        QString fileName;
};
```

and then use the member variable

```
void fileTxt::setFileTxt(Ui::Dialog *ui)
{
    fileName="test.txt" //uses class member fileName
}

void fileTxt::elabFileTxt(Ui::Dialog *ui)
{
    ui->label_7->setText(fileName);
}
```